# Simultaneously generating threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Is it possible to generate and run n number of threads at the same time? I want to run around 10000 threads for 5 seconds but I'm not able to achieve this as only a certain number of threads are able to get executed within the 5 seconds for which the program runs. A major number of the threads do not run. (Execution time of all the threads together should be 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. You cannot run `n` threads simultaneously in Python. This is due to Python's Global Interpreter Lock, or [GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf), as you may find online. Parallel execution of Python threads is not possible. Only one thread is allowed to access the interpreter at a time because of the GIL.

If you want to achieve such a behavior, try [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Multiprocessing seems to be too heavyweight for my application and results in the pc crashing. Is there any other solution?